# VBA Excel - Formatting Date in a TextBox using a validation

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm working on a DATE validation. The date format that I'm going to use is `mm/dd/yyyy`. May I ask if it is possible if a `/` will be **automatically** inserted while typing? And, I'm also thinking if how can I validate if the value is a real date or not.

The code below allows the textbox to accept `numbers` and a `/`. It is under the `Class File`.

```
If KeyAscii >= 47 And KeyAscii <= 57 Then
      Debug.Print tb.Name, "date"
   Else
      MsgBox "The value should be in a DATE format: mm/dd/yyyy", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
      Debug.Print tb.Name, "other"
      KeyAscii = 0
End If
```

Should I stick in modifying the `Class` file or is there a way for me to do it on the `Userform` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the automatic "/", I tried using

```
If tb.SelStart = 2 Or tb.SelStart = 5 Then
    tb.Text = tb.Text & "/"
End If
```

into the texbox keypress event of the userform, and it seems to be working great.

This is an example with some restrictions on different numbers in different positions: (Userform code)

```
Private Sub tb_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
If KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57 Then 'This textbox only allows for numbers 0-9

'restrict lenght
    If Len(tb.Text) = 10 Then KeyAscii = 0
    
'first number of month has to be 0 or 1
    If tb.SelStart = 0 Then
        If KeyAscii < 48 Or KeyAscii > 49 Then KeyAscii = 0

'entire month has to be more than 0 and less than 13
    ElseIf tb.SelStart = 1 Then
        If Left(tb.Text, 1) = "1" Then
            If KeyAscii < 48 Or KeyAscii > 50 Then KeyAscii = 0
        Else
            If KeyAscii < 49 Then KeyAscii = 0
        End If
        
'first number of day has to be between 0 and 3 and gets the "/"
    ElseIf tb.SelStart = 2 Or tb.SelStart = 3 Then
        If KeyAscii < 48 Or KeyAscii > 51 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        Else
            tb.Text = Left(tb.Text, 2) & "/"
        End If

'entire day of day has to be more than 0 and less than 31
    ElseIf tb.SelStart = 4 Then
        If Mid(tb.Text, 4, 1) = "0" Then
            If KeyAscii < 49 Then KeyAscii = 0
        ElseIf Mid(tb.Text, 4, 1) = "3" Then
            If KeyAscii < 48 Or KeyAscii > 49 Then KeyAscii = 0
        ElseIf Not Mid(tb.Text, 4, 1) = "1" And Not Mid(tb.Text, 4, 1) = "2" Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        End If
    
'first number of year has to be between 1 and 2 and gets the "/"
    ElseIf tb.SelStart = 5 Or tb.SelStart = 6 Then
        If KeyAscii < 49 Or KeyAscii > 50 Then
            KeyAscii = 0
        Else
            tb.Text = Left(tb.Text, 5) & "/"
        End If
    
    End If
Else
    KeyAscii = 0
End If
End Sub
```

This is an example on how to restric the user to enter anything but a proper date*.

.*You can still enter things like 02/30 or use the paste function to enter whatever.

Answer (score 1):

### Format TextBox Input & Validate

The code below will automatically add in the slashes for the format you want (Can be dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy). There needs to be the public boolean in the at the top to prevent it triggering itself when the slashes get added. It also checks the date once the date is full entered and will turn the text red should it be an invalid date. Just tweak what you need to (Namely replace the `TextBox1` name with the name of your textbox and it should work great.

I also just added some notes on the side of some lines so you know what they do.

```
Public HaltChanges As Boolean

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim t As String

If HaltChanges = True Then Exit Sub 'Prevents retrigger from changing the text

t = Me.TextBox1.Text
If Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = vbRed Then Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = vbwindows 'Reset to original color
If Len(t) < 1 Then Exit Sub 'If textbox is empty
If Len(t) > 10 Then 'Date should be no greater than 10 characters including / so prevent anything else being typed
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Left(t, 10)
    Exit Sub
End If
If Len(t) = 10 And IsDate(t) = False Then 'if has 10 characters (full date) and it's not a real date then make text red
    Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = vbRed
End If

HaltChanges = True
If Not IsNumeric(Right(t, 1)) Then 'Check if input is a number or not
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Left(t, Len(t) - 1) 'Remove last entered character if not a number
ElseIf Len(t) >= 3 And Mid(t, 3, 1) <> "/" Then 'These ones are to add the slashes
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Left(t, 2) & "/" & Right(t, 1)
ElseIf Len(t) >= 6 And Mid(t, 6, 1) <> "/" Then
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Left(t, 5) & "/" & Right(t, 1)
End If
t = Me.TextBox1.Text
HaltChanges = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a note. You can use `Ctl + H` inside the VBA editor to find and replace `Me.Textbox` with `Me.YourTextBoxName` so you don't have to change each one.

Comment: This seems to work if you will have one textbox to be validated, but I tried it and it worked so thank you very much!

Comment: Well you didnt state anything about multiple text boxes... ah well.

Comment: Oh right. I'm so sorry. My fault. I thought I put it there

Comment: You can put this into each one though, depending how many you have. If you're using a class module this will work with that.

Comment: Yes yes. I'm going to use this on my codes. Thank you so much!